# Fillable Text Form with auto-scalable height

Tags: hyperref, forms, textfield

I'm trying to set many fillable Text boxes for a pdf document.
However, I want the HEIGHT of the Text Form to ve variable, adjusting its height depending on tyhe amount of text entered by the user. As an example,

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
\TextField[name=multilinetextbox,multiline=true, width=linewidth,height=5in,charsize=0pt]{}                                      
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

I've seen solutions that adjust the character (font) size but that's not what I'm looking for.
Any help would be much apprecited.
Kind Regards

Comment: While the internals of eforms are ajustables, the externals (sich as size) are not.  To change the size you would need to recompile the page.  What you **can** do is have the conents scroll up and down within the given window.  See `\listbox`, page 11, eforms manual.

Comment: Thx vm John.
If you could provide a MWE would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a `\textField` supports scrolling too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eforms}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
\textField[\Ff{\FfMultiline}\V{Default text which must not be a macro. If you keep typing or click the button in the corner, a scroll bar will appear.}]{scrollbox.1}{2in}{0.5in}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```